# How do I calculate total utility under discounted utility framework

Tags: microeconomics, utility, behavioral-economics

Suppose we are given an instantaneous utility function and discounted rate with budget constraint. Using the exponentially discounted utility function, we can find the optimal consumption stream of a person. Now we know the instantaneous utility and also the total utility of different time(period). But what if we are asked to compare which one is better off given change of utility function?

I think it is time to calculate total utility. For instance, the utility of having one burger is 1, with discounted rate 0.5. In this case, if I choose to eat one burger today and one burger tomorrow, for current point of view, I will get utility = 1+0.5*1=1.5. But what is the total utility of these two days? Is it simply 1+1=2?

Comment: What is "total utility?"

Comment: Well, it doesn't ask for total utility. It asks to find out which type of the person (HDU, EDU) is better off. So I think I should calculate U(c0)+U(c1)+U(c2) and take the larger one. This sum is what I mean by total utility in the context

Comment: I don't think it makes much sense to ask whether someone would be better off with a different utility function.

Comment: Then what if we want to compare the difference between a person who decide consumption or saving, with another plan of comsumption/buying annuity? Using same utility function and exponential discounted utility, we will get different consumption streams. How do I figure out which plan is better by using utility

Comment: I don't know if I should include the discount factor, consider the EDU from period 0 point of view, or simply add utility gains from different periods together

Comment: If you have a discounted utility model, you sum up all discounted instantaneous utilities along the stream.